# How can I put the value of the array object using useState when rendering for the first time in Reactnative?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have an object array called targetFarm, and when I run the map function, the value comes out like this.

```
targetFarm.children.map((item) => item.children.map((v) => console.log("v:", v)));

v = {
    name: "coffee"
}

v = {
    name: "tea"
}

v= {
    name: "icecream"
}
```

What I want to do is put the value of this v.name in an array form using useState in the box constant. as below

```
box = [
    "coffee",
    "tea",
    "icecream",
]
```

But when I used my code
This error pops up.

"Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

```
const [box, setBox] = useState(

    targetFarm.children.map((item) => {
        item.children.map((v) => {
            box.push(v.name)
        })
    })
)
```

then How can i fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to do is put the value of this v.name in an array form using useState in the box constant

You can use `map` and `flatMap` like below

```
targetFarm.children.flatMap((item) => item.children.map((v) => v.name);
```

> "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

From your code, `box` has not been initialized yet, so `undefined` does not have `push` method. That's why it's throwing that error.

If you want to assign the default state value for `box`, you can check the below example.

```
const [box, setBox] = useState(
    targetFarm.children.flatMap((item) => 
        item.children.map((v) => v.name)
    )
)
```